# VS не видит Converter

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот имею вот такой `converter` в неймспейсе `BrainTrain`.

Вот файл `ByteToImageConverter`:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace BrainTrain
{
    public class ByteToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(value as byte[]))
            {
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.BeginInit();
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.StreamSource = ms;
                image.EndInit();
                return image;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

А вот xaml окна:

```
<Window x:Class="BrainTrain.Windows.WorkWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:glob='clr-namespace:BrainTrain'
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WorkWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <glob:ByteToImageConverter x:Key='ByteToImageConverter' />
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

На строчке  ошибка:

> Имя "ByteToImageConverter" не существует в пространстве имен "clr-namespace:BrainTrain"

И не компилируется проект. Как действовать в такой ситуации и из-за чего она возникает

Comment: Очень советую вам ReSharper, он вам сам всего 1 кликом задаст нужный namespace в XAML. По поводу ошибки, `clr-namespace:BrainTrain` и namespace где находится `class ByteToImageConverter` одинаковы? Или может этот класс находится внутри другого класса? Также в WPF есть ужасный глюк, когда он не находит до перекомпиляции проекта ресурсы, пробовали сделать "Очистить" и "Пересобрать" ?

Comment: `public class ByteToImageConverter`

Comment: @tym32167 сделал класс публичным, без изменений.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, очистил и собрал заново, ничего нового.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ класс ByteToImageConverter в `using BrainTrain`

Comment: @Aqua Что бы нам не гадать, может сделаете самодостаточный пример, ну или проект предоставите?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ думаю, полный код файлов будет достаточно...

Comment: Кавычки двойные еще попробуйте :)

Comment: @Aqua Нет, не достаточно. В точности копирую и все успешно. ([XAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtiTr.png) и ваш [код](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCCD3.png))

Comment: @EvgeniyZ дать ссылку на проект?

Comment: @Aqua Если это поможет и там будет явно видна проблема, то да.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EohNSkhOQwNNPugJb4m_tecFyNcK3IHU?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас висит ряд ошибок, которые мешают компилятору собрать грамотно проект.

[image: Errors]

Первая говорит об ошибке в файле `App.xaml`, заходим туда и видим строку:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BrainTrain.Converters"
```

У вас в проекте нету ни одного класса, который содержал бы такой namespace, значит строку нужно удалить.

Пробуем пересобрать проект и вуаля! Все успешно заработало и `ByteToImageConverter` успешно найдет.

Comment: Исходя из первой ошибки, другую исправить вообще никак? Спасибо, заработало)

Comment: @Aqua О какой ошибке вы говорите? Вроде их две уберет простое удаление указанной строки.

Comment: Ну у меня все работает, просто понять хочу. Первая ошибка мешала работе проекта, и из-за этого из было 2? Странно как-то. Или просто первая ошибка мешала сборке?

Comment: @Aqua Проект обычно собирается со стартовой точки, в WPF это app.xaml.cs В нем у вас критическая ошибка, которая не давала проекту собраться и обновить все данные. Из за того, что данные о проекте не обновились - конструктор считал, что такого класса не существует. Так что да, тут просто первая ошибка мешала сборке. 2-я ошибка происходит из за того, что конструктор студии довольно багованый в плане XAML и для того, что бы он увидел новый класс - проект надо успешно пересобрать.

Comment: Все.  Это все что мне нужно было знать, что бы такого больше не было. Спасибо ещё раз

Answer (score 0):

Такая же ошибка:

> Имя "MyConverter" не существует в пространстве имен "clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"

возникла на пустом месте при переносе UserControl из одного проекта в другой при полном соответствии пространств имён и всего остального.

Помогло обновление VS, очистка и перестройка проекта. Что именно из этого было решающим - непонятно. Только возникла проблема с прикреплёнными свойствами UserControl, которые никак не хотели подхватываться в xaml, хотя IntelliSense подсказывал их при вводе.

Помогло удаление и вставка на прежнее место одного из свойств.

Comment: думаю тут больше перестройка проекта помогла.