# Почему не удаётся найти ресурс?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-шаблоны

В проект добавил файл словаря ресурсов `DifferentElements.xaml`, при попытки собрать проекта возникает исключение:

**System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ""Задание свойства "System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source" вызвало исключение.": номер строки "14" и позиция в строке "18"." IOException: Не удается найти ресурс "resources/styles/differentelemets.xaml".**

Так же в разметке в App.xaml пишет ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

XAML:

```
<Application x:Class="ToEachHisOwn.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             xmlns:l="clr-namespace:ToEachHisOwn"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ToEachHisOwn.ViewModels"
             StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepPurple" SecondaryColor="Lime"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml"/>

                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Styles/DifferentElemets.xaml"/>
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="1111.xaml"/>-->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Для теста создал ещё один словарь по пути `/Resources2/Styles2/DifferentElemets2.xaml` - такую же ошибку пишет и такое же исключение выдаёт, если не класть файл словаря в папки, то приложение собирается. Как такое поведение исправить?

Ошибка и св-ва файла словаря:

[image: Ошибка и св-ва файла словаря]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Список ошибок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дайте скрин окна со всеми ошибками. Также дайте скрин свойств этого словаря (конкретно интересует "действие при сборке"). Ну а сейчас я могу просто предположить, что это либо глюк студии (уберите строку подключения, очистите проект и пересоберите), либо у вас есть другая ошибка (которая пишется в окне "список ошибок").

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Добавил в описание вопроса скрины. В списке ошибок есть одна (я её показал на первом скрине, где показываю её в App.xaml), строки подключения нет, а как понять "очистить проект"? Я удалил кэш студии (файл .vs), но не помогло.

Comment: Что-то меня этот `AdditionalFiles` смущает, должно быть `Страница`(`Page`), может конечно с переводом что или с версией студии... А по поводу ошибки - вы не то, что я просил скинули. В студии есть окно, где она пишет **все** ошибки, которые найдет, зовется оно "Список ошибок" и выглядит [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLmaA.png), вот именно оно меня и интересует, ибо как я вам сказал выше, у вам может быть ошибка в другом месте. Вот примерно про [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/933883/220553) я говорю.

Comment: Очистить проект - это просто убрать строку проблемную, потом тыкнуть на проект "ПКМ" и выбрать "Очистить", а далее в том же месте выбрать "Пересобрать". Либо закрыть студию, затем удалить `bin` и `obj` директории, открыть проект и проделать опять же "очистить" и "пересобрать".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Проделал всё, но не помогло. После удаления `bin` и `obj` в списке ошибок ругался на `Locator`, мол, не мог его найти, а после пересборки, стал ругаться на `<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/DifferentElemets.xaml"/>`

Comment: Но вы пропустили одну вещь, которую я вам сказал: `Что-то меня этот AdditionalFiles смущает, должно быть Страница(Page)`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не пропустил, это сразу сделал и не помогло. Ещё замечено, что если выполнить сборку (ctrl+b), то она успешно выполняется без ошибок, если через (Run), то не даёт.

Comment: Ну как же не помогло то? Вот чистый проект WPF у меня, делаю прям в корне файл словаря, подключаю его как и вы и, у меня [успешно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25WA6.png) отрабатывает проект. [Меняю](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbxFn.png) тут лишь `Page` на `AdditionalFiles`, очищаю проект (как сказал выше (без удаление папок)) и вижу [вашу ошибку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpVRR.png). Меняю опять обратно на `Page` и получаю опять [рабочий](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BIQJ.png) проект. Так что извиняйте, я тогда без понятия что у вас там "не помогло".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ето победа. Помогло! Респектище Вам за помощь в поиске решения.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Опубликуйте как ответ, пригодится другим тоже.

Comment: @VladD Я против такого на SO. Ценности в этом просто не вижу, ибо допустим при создании словаря, студия автоматом ему ставит `Page`, а значит автор сам накрутил что-то лишнего и это, как по мне, можно приравнивать к банальной опечатке. Так что, лично я ответ писать не буду, а если кому-то нужна репутация или считает это прям полезным вопросом, то пусть пишет ответ)

Comment: @VladD Я не менял эту опцию после создания словаря. Зачем мне менять эту опцию у словаря, если я не знаю, что она делает? Дело Ваше. Помогать разобраться или показывать свои принципы. Естественно, я оставлю ответ, наверняка поможет кому-нибудь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а по мне так очевидная причина сбоя найдена. И ответ вполне может оказаться полезен другим пользователям. Особенно если автор распишет, как это работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо @EvgeniyZ, помог разобраться с данной ошибкой.

> Что-то меня этот `AdditionalFiles` смущает, должно быть `Страница`(`Page`)

Оказалось, что каким-то образом в свойствах XAML файла словаря была установлена опция **Действие при сборке** - `AdditionalFiles`, которую нужно было изменить на `Pages`.